# How do I use BOOST BinaryFunction concept?

Tags: c++, boost, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

There's no documentation that I could find, nor anything relevant that I saw when doing a google search:

I have function which I want to produce a signature of:

```
(void)(int,int)
```

And so when I run these two functions as:

```
void dosomething(int x, int y);
void dosomethingwront(float x, float y);
```

Through:

```
// Should succeed
boost::BinaryFunction<dosomething,void,int,int>
// Should fail
boost::BinaryFunction<dosomethingwrong,void,int,int>
```

Compilation fails because it doesn't like the first parameter type. Unfortunately I'm uncertain of what they mean by `<class Func,...>` in their documentation. If I had those two functions, how could I test those concepts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template parameters have to be a types. 
 You could use `decltype((dosomething))`.  Note that your concept won't fail for `dosomethingwront` because `int` is convertible to `float` and the concept checks whether the binary function is *callable* with `int`, rather than inspecting the function signature.

```
#include <boost/concept_check.hpp>

void dosomething(int x, int y);
void dosomethingwront(float x, float y);

int main() {
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::BinaryFunction<decltype((dosomething)),void,int,int>));
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((boost::BinaryFunction<decltype((dosomethingwront)),void,int,int>));
}
```

If you want to check for this concept rigorously on the basis of function arguments, you can do so with type traits based on explicit template specialization.  The following does not exhaust all possible const and volatile qualifications.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename F>
struct is_void_int_int : std::false_type {};

// Free function
template <>
struct is_void_int_int<void(int, int)> : std::true_type {};

// Pointer to function
template <>
struct is_void_int_int<void (*)(int, int)> : std::true_type {};

// Reference to function
template <>
struct is_void_int_int<void (&)(int, int)> : std::true_type {};

// Pointer to member function
template <typename C>
struct is_void_int_int<void (C::*)(int, int)> : std::true_type {};

void dosomething(int x, int y);
void dosomethingwront(float x, float y);

struct A {
    void operator()(int, int) {}
};

struct B {
    void bar(int, int) {}
};

int main() {
    static_assert(is_void_int_int<decltype(dosomething)>::value, "!");
    static_assert(is_void_int_int<decltype((dosomething))>::value, "!");
    static_assert(is_void_int_int<decltype(&dosomething)>::value, "!");
    static_assert(is_void_int_int<decltype(&A::operator())>::value, "!");
    static_assert(is_void_int_int<decltype(&B::bar)>::value, "!");
  //static_assert(is_void_int_int<decltype(dosomethingwront)>::value, "!"); // BOOM!
}
```